# asp.net mvc routing depending on session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an *ASP.Net MVC* site and I want that every request to images of my site

```
  /images/image_name.png
```

are redirected to

```
  /images/{skin}/image_name.png
```

where `{skin}` is session dependant.

and I would like to make the same for any type of files (css, some json file for configurations,...)

I was asking if it is possible in *ASP.Net MVC* to hook requests at `HttpListener` level to make there the correct switch depending on the session.

Thanks a lot